# How to replace the ' Call-time pass-by-reference ' on PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, pointers, pass-by-reference

Considering that PHP has already deprecated a few functions and functionallitys, I would like to refactory my codes to fit it on php 5.3.

now, I have to eliminate all the 'Call-time pass-by-reference' . So, I have three questions:

1 - If I replace:

```
$myclass->myfunc(&$myvar);
```

by

```
$myvar = $myclass->myfunc($myvar);
```

will work ?

2 - what do I do if I have something like that?

```
$myclass->myfunc(&$myVar, &$ourvar);
```

3 - How about

```
$x = &new myclass();
```

Thanks for your time, any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First, are you familiar with what call-time pass by reverence is? Normal pass by reference is accomplished by the function declaring that certain arguments are pass by reference by prepending a `&` to the parameter in its declaration.

Call-time pass by reference means that the function is declared to take those arguments by value, and you are changing its behavior to pass-by-reference after the fact. Call-time pass by reference shouldn't really ever be necessary. Every function should have a specific purpose, and to correctly accomplish its purpose, it should either always take an argument by reference, or always take it by value. It is bad to make a function do something it was not designed to do.

Responding to your questions about `$myclass->myfunc(&$myvar);` and `$myclass->myfunc(&$myVar, &$ourvar);` I would say that, if you need to pass by reference to that function, then it should be declared as always pass by reference. i.e.

```
function myfunc(&$x, &$y) { ... }
```

Then to use it you just call it without the `&`

```
$myclass->myfunc($myVar, $ourvar);
```

`$x = &new myclass();` is completely irrelevant. You are not passing anything. It is still valid syntax.